# Почему свойство ItemHeight компонента TListBox не изменяется?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Почему свойство ItemHeight компонента TListBox не изменяется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство `ItemHeight` применимо только в случае, если свойство `Style <> lbStandard`. Т.е. вы сами рисуете элементы (варианты стиля с фразой `OwnerDraw`) либо `ListBox` не хранит у себя элементы, а запрашивает их у вас по требованию (варианты стиля с фразой `Virtual`). Только в этих случаях ему требуется указывать высоту элементов. В случае `lbStandard` он сам её вычисляет.

Answer (score 0):

Style = lbOwnerDrawFixed